# Joining nimaz in ist rakat in rakuh

Tags: salat

I joined in ist rakat and jamaat was in raku. Do I have to repeat ist rakat OR Joining in rakuh will complete ist rakat.

Answer (score 0):

If any part of rakat is missed in jamaat then it means your whole rakat is missed. You could repeat rakat after jamat accordingly.